# Unable to start Tessera node for Quorum

Tags: ethereum, consensus, quorum

I have set up Quorom 3 nodes by following the guide and now I am setting of the Tessera nodes for the 3 nodes. however the Tessera node are not starting up.

https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/#tessera

Here are logs captured.

```
2019-11-09 00:57:30.942 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @7972ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2019-11-09 00:57:31.069 [main] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Starting http://localhost:9081
2019-11-09 00:57:31.075 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-04-18T19:45:35.259Z; git: aa1c656c315c011c01e7b21aabb04066635b9f67; jvm 1.8.0_231-b11
2019-11-09 00:57:32.051 [main] WARN  o.g.jersey.internal.inject.Providers - A provider com.quorum.tessera.thirdparty.RawTransactionResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.quorum.tessera.thirdparty.RawTransactionResource will be ignored. 
2019-11-09 00:57:32.519 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@37c5284a{/,null,AVAILABLE}
Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9081
2019-11-09 00:57:32.540 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopping Jersey server at http://localhost:9081
2019-11-09 00:57:32.555 [Thread-2] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@41853299{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9081}
2019-11-09 00:57:32.782 [Thread-2] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@37c5284a{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
2019-11-09 00:57:32.787 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopped Jersey server at http://localhost:9081
2019-11-09 00:57:32.787 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopping Jersey server at unix:/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/tm.ipc
2019-11-09 00:57:32.787 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopped Jersey server at unix:/home/srikant/Desktop/fromscratch/new-node-1t/tm.ipc
2019-11-09 00:57:32.788 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopping Jersey server at http://localhost:9001
2019-11-09 00:57:32.788 [Thread-2] INFO  c.quorum.tessera.server.JerseyServer - Stopped Jersey server at http://localhost:9001
```

Any help would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Failed to bind' message implies that the port is in use.
Perhaps Tessera is already running?
You can use `lsof -nP -i4TCP:9081` to check which process is using port 9081.

Comment: Thanks Satpal for your suggestion. However, I crossed the step by initializing the nodes in the reverse order. Now I want to attach the tessera config with my quorum instance.. and getting the below error.............panic: MustNew: Failed to connect to Constellation (./new-node-1t/tm.ipc): Constellation Node API did not respond to upcheck request

goroutine 1 [running]:-----------  However I am able to hit the upcheck request @http://localhost:9081/upcheck

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue.  I restarted the VM and then it worked